# How to concat the parameter value in the file name using snowflake scripting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to concat the parameter value with file name. I am passing sysdate as parameter, when I `call sp_demo`, I give value as string `sp_demo('20220429')`. it is not working.

I guess it is not capturing the date value correctly. snowflake scripting is new thing.

```
create or replace procedure sp_demo(sysdate varchar)
    returns varchar not null
    language sql
    execute as caller 
as
$$
begin
    copy into stg.tb_demo (name, id,  address)
        from @stg.demo_stage/DEMO.:sysdate.psv.gz 
        file_format = (format_name = 'stg.demo_ff',
          error_on_column_count_mismatch = true, encoding = 'iso-8859-1');
end;
$$;
```

Comment: `:sysdate:` should be `:sysdate` to use the variable, but I have having troubles make a similar setup to test if that operation handles varaibles cleanly (they don't all)

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I made a typing  mistake. it is actually :sysdate . but it is not capturing the date. syntax is correct. something wrong ... :)

Comment: ya, I have been playing with it. there are other places the variable substitution does not work yet. like `table_alias.:col_name_var` gets upset about the dot. but making a new var works. Was search of where I has shown that recently.

Comment: it is very new. none is familiar with it..  :(

Comment: Thank you very much @SimeonPilgrim it is working. Great Solution... You made my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not a full solution but you can caputure the instruction and then run that.

I didn't have files to copy that made sense so I flipped to trying to use LIST to show the files are there, etc.

```
create or replace procedure sp_demo(sysdate varchar)
    returns varchar not null
    language sql
as
$$
begin
    let sql text := 'list @~'||:sysdate;
    let res resultset := (execute immediate :sql);
end;
$$;
```

albeit, LIST results are not a capturable thing..

so for you code:

```
create or replace procedure sp_demo(sysdate varchar)
    returns varchar not null
    language sql
as
$$
begin
    let sql text := 'copy into stg.tb_demo(name, id, address) from @stg.demo_stage/DEMO.' || :sysdate || '.psv.gz file_format = (format_name = ''stg.demo_ff'', error_on_column_count_mismatch = true, encoding = ''iso-8859-1'')';
     return sql;
    --execute immediate :sql;
end;
$$;
```

```
call sp_demo('1234');
```

gives:

`copy into stg.tb_demo(name, id, address) from @stg.demo_stage/DEMO.1234.psv.gz file_format = (format_name = 'stg.demo_ff', error_on_column_count_mismatch = true, encoding = 'iso-8859-1')`